unsafe extern "system" fn service_main How to pass variables
I try to write a windows service using winapi
How to pass "heventlog" of main function to service_main using
In other languages, we can use global variables. How to deal with this situation in Rust?
Code
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use windows::core::{w, PWSTR};
use windows::Win32::Foundation::HANDLE;
use windows::Win32::System::Services::{
    RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerW, SetServiceStatus, StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW,
    SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, SERVICE_RUNNING, SERVICE_START_PENDING,
    SERVICE_STATUS, SERVICE_STOPPED, SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
};

unsafe extern "system" fn service_control_handler(dwcontrol: u32) {
    match dwcontrol {
        SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP => return,
        _ => {}
    }
}

unsafe extern "system" fn service_main(_dwnumservicesargs: u32, _lpserviceargvectors: *mut PWSTR) {
    // How to use heventlog

    let mut lpservicestatus = SERVICE_STATUS {
        dwServiceType: SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
        dwCurrentState: SERVICE_START_PENDING,
        dwControlsAccepted: SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP,
        dwWin32ExitCode: 0,
        dwServiceSpecificExitCode: 0,
        dwCheckPoint: 0,
        dwWaitHint: 0,
    };

    let lpservicename = w!("Demo Service");
    let hservicestatus =
        RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerW(lpservicename, Some(service_control_handler)).unwrap();

    lpservicestatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
    SetServiceStatus(hservicestatus, &mut lpservicestatus).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    use windows::Win32::System::EventLog::RegisterEventSourceW;
    let heventlog = unsafe { RegisterEventSourceW(None, w!("Demo Service")) }.unwrap();
    let heventlog: Arc<Mutex<HANDLE>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(heventlog));
    // How heventlog is passed to service_main

    let mut lp_service_name = "Demo Service\0".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<u16>>();
    let lp_service_name = PWSTR::from_raw(lp_service_name.as_mut_ptr());

    let lpservicestarttable = [
        SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW {
            lpServiceName: lp_service_name,
            lpServiceProc: Some(service_main),
        },
        SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW {
            lpServiceName: PWSTR::null(),
            lpServiceProc: None,
        },
    ]
    .as_ptr();

    unsafe { StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW(lpservicestarttable) }.unwrap();
}

service_main can use heventlog to record logs

RegisterEventSourceW() returns a HANDLE that implements Copy, Send, and Sync. You can share it much like you would share an i32. I don't know why you would want to do that, though.

You can have global static variables in Rust.  In this case, you could for example store the HANDLE within a global OnceLock:
use std::sync::OnceLock;

static H_EVENT_LOG: OnceLock<HANDLE> = OnceLock::new();

unsafe extern "system" fn service_main(
    _dwnumservicesargs: u32,
    _lpserviceargvectors: *mut PWSTR,
) {
    // use H_EVENT_LOG.get().unwrap()
    // ...
}

fn main() {
    let heventlog = unsafe { RegisterEventSourceW(None, w!("Demo Service")) }.unwrap();
    H_EVENT_LOG.set(heventlog).unwrap();
    // ...
}

